# Incrementing row value by previous row result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help with one script.
I have table like this.

```
DateFrom    DateTo
1.1.2013    5.1.2013
2.3.2013    5.3.2013
25.5.2013   5.6.2013
.
.
```

And I need script with this result.

```
DateFrom    DateTo     Result 
1.1.2013    5.1.2013    5       - DateTo - DateFrom     
2.3.2013    5.3.2013    9       - DateTo - DateFrom + Result from previous row
25.5.2013   5.6.2013    21      - DateTo - DateFrom + Result from previous row
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a previous If you are using SQL Server 2012 or newer you can use analytic functions for this (I think new versions of Sybase also support this but I am not familiar enough with it to confirm this, let alone tell you in which version it started to be supported):

```
SELECT  DateFrom,
        DateTo,
        Result = SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, DateFrom, DateTo) + 1) OVER(ORDER BY DateFrom)
FROM    T;
```

However, if you are using older versions, of SQL Server and Sybase, or all versions of Access you will have to use a correlated subquery, something like:

```
SELECT  DateFrom,
        DateTo,
        Result = (  SELECT  SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, DateFrom, DateTo) + 1)
                    FROM    T AS T2
                    WHERE   T2.DateFrom <= T.DateFrom
                )
FROM    T;
```